# Встроенная подпись в pdf linux?

Tags: цифровая-подпись

Установил КриптоПро CSP 3.9 на Linux CentOS 7,
Установил сертификат УЦ и Личный,
Пробовал подписывать файл при помощи cryptcp, подписывает гостом 2001 года, pdf файл после не открывается, а во втором случае подпись получается не встроенная в файл,
Пробовал при помощи csptestf, файл на выходе получился чуть больше весом, чем исходный но ADOBE ACROBAT подпись никакую не видит.
Как нормально подписать pdf файл встроенной подписью в Linux?
Пожалуйста откликнитесь на проблему! спасибо.
Хотел попробовать подписать запустив Криптопро pdf через wine, но без графического интерфейса его походу не установить

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте еще связку **iText + КриптоПро JCP**, должно помочь в вашей проблеме

Comment: К сожалению нет людей владеющих java, больше не знаете никаких способов случайно?

Comment: К сожалению не знаю